# Creating a dataframe from strings in text file using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file which is presented in the following way

```
Category: name1 = value1
Category: name2 = value2
Category: name3 = value3
```

I have a python script that filters through the text file to find the category name but I want to create a data frame that would drop the category name at the start then have name1, name2, name3 as the column headers and then the values listed in the rows below

Do you have any suggestions on how id do this or any recommended documentation to review?

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe that you'd like to achieve, based on that text file? e.g. `pd.DataFrame({'col':['cell1', 'cell2']})`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see it, there are two parts to your question. One is how to parse your file into a dataframe in a some form, and the second is transform it into a specific shape.

For the first step, let's assume the file `data` looks like this

```
Category: name1 = value1
Category: name2 = value2
Category: name3 = value3
Category: name1 = value4
Category: name2 = value5
Category: name3 = value6
```

(I added a few rows to make this more interesting)
Then we can parse it onto a dataframe by specifying the separator to be either `:` optionally surrounded by spaces, or `=` optionally surrounded by spaces:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = '\s*:\s*|\s*=\s*', engine='python', header=None)
```

Now `df` would look like this:

```
    0         1      2
--  --------  -----  ------
 0  Category  name1  value1
 1  Category  name2  value2
 2  Category  name3  value3
 3  Category  name1  value4
 4  Category  name2  value5
 5  Category  name3  value6
```

To beat this into shape, we f8irst drop the column 0:

```
df1 = df.drop(columns = 0)
```

Finally, we groupby, reindex and unstack it to give it the right shape:

```
df1['rowidx'] = df1.groupby(1, group_keys = False).cumcount()
(df1.set_index(['rowidx',1])
    .unstack()
    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
)
```

The output is:

```
  rowidx  name1    name2    name3
--------  -------  -------  -------
       0  value1   value2   value3
       1  value4   value5   value6
```